# R: Arima() daily prediction series with variable forecast horizon (forecast())

Tags: r, time-series, finance, predict, arima

I have estimated an ARIMA model (actually a list of models) on a daily time series x_0 through x_n. Given the estimated model, I "simply" would like to generate a vector (without re-estimation) Y_(n+1),j through y_m,j where each element y_i,j (i in n+1:m), is the expectation of the process j-days ahead (j is not constant), conditioned on x_(i-1),x_(i-2),...

The problem I am having is with forecast(). Namely, I do not know how to pass updated x-values to forecast() for each row in the test, where in each row i am essentially creating a new forecast object. I have looked all over Stack the last few days, but have not been able to find a solution. I am open to advice in python as well if it solves my problem.

for some context, if it helps, I am forecasting my variable (the VIX index) each day, over a period defined by its VVIX futures contracts time to maturity (which decreases and jumps, as contracts in the series mature, and are replaced by longer maturity contracts respectively.)

If you need code, or other examples, I am glad to provide, but the concept is pretty simple to understand, so hopefully someone knows the limits of this library a little better than me. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

note: i understand that I may have to calculate the expectation myself, but I have a research meeting soon and want to know if there is away to accomplish this with forecast(), thanks!

~Carmine

Edit: here is code to replicate. after the Arima() object is stored in 'model' I need to create (in this example) a vector with 50 entries, where each entry is the expectation at time t (t in 51:100) of x at time T (n_step ahead). Any advice welcome!!

```
x <- rnorm(100)+1
train_test <- list(train=x[1:50],test=x[51:100])
n_step <- ceiling(runif(n=50,min=1,max=20))
model <- Arima(train_test[[1]],order=c(1,0,1),method="ML")
```

Comment: If you can share code and/or sample of data, it will require less work and luck for people to help.

Comment: Hey Jon, thank you! I wasn't sure what to put exactly, and felt a conceptual explanation would be sufficient. I have updated my post with some code to recreate the problem within your GE. Please let me know if you have any other recommendations! I would love to get past this stage!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program to preform the forecasts inquired about in this post. The code is highly specific to my research, but I have made a simplified example, and will share it here. Please note, the coefficient indices in the arima model object are not constant. I just aligned all model coefficients into a nx7 matrix (i use up to 3 ar, ma terms and intercept), and looped row by row. Hope it helps someone, because it definitely would have helped me! Any advice on revisions or improvement welcome!

-Carmine

```
library(forecast)

train <- vix$Close[1:1000] ;test <- vix$Close[1001:2000]
fit <- Arima(train, order=c(2,0,2));coefs <- as.numeric(fit$coef)
xreg <- train;eps <- fit$residuals
n_step <- rep(10:3,125);nth_step_fc <- numeric()

for(i in 1:length(test)){
  n_step_fc <- numeric(n_step[i])
  xreg_temp <- xreg;eps_temp <- eps
  for(j in 1:n_step[i]){          
    n_step_fc[j] <- coefs[1]*(xreg_temp[length(xreg_temp)]-coefs[5])+ # ar1
      coefs[2]*(xreg_temp[length(xreg_temp)-1]-coefs[5])+             # ar2
      coefs[3]*(eps_temp[length(eps_temp)]+             # ma1
      coefs[4]*eps_temp[length(eps_temp)-1]+             # ma2
      coefs[5]                                             # intercept
    eps_temp <- append(eps,0)                            # mean est (not point)
    xreg_temp <- append(xreg,n_step_fc[j])
  }
  nth_step_fc[i] <- n_step_fc[j]
  eps_i <- n_step_fc[1]-test[i]
  eps <- append(eps,eps_i)
  xreg <- append(xreg,test[i])
}
```